# Evaluate $\int _{|z|=2}ze^{\frac{3}{z}} dz$

Tags: integration

How to integrate this

$\int _{|z|=2}ze^{\frac{3}{z}} dz$

I tried to do this by substituting $z=2e^{i\phi};0\leq \phi\leq 2\pi$

But cannot proceed further.Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{|z|=2}ze^{3/z}\,dz=-2\pi iRes(f,\infty)=2\pi iRes\left(\frac{1}{z^2}f(1/z),0\right)$$ where , $f(z)=ze^{3/z}$.

Now , $\frac{1}{z^2}f(1/z)=\frac{1}{z^3}e^{3z}$

So, $Res\left(\frac{1}{z^2}f(1/z),0\right)=Res\left(\frac{1}{z^3}e^{3z},0\right)=\frac{1}{2!}\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}e^{3z}=\frac{9}{2}$

**So, required answer will be $9\pi i$.**

Comment: how to get the formula? please explain

Comment: Do you know that sum of the residues at all finite poles and at the point $\infty$ is equal to zero ?

Comment: yes ;i am asking about the second one i.e. $\frac{1}{z^2}f(1/z)$

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity)

Answer (score -3):

Expanding and integrating term by term we end up with integrating 9/(2z) round the circle given. The answer is 2i(pi)(9/2)=9i(pi).

Comment: did not get that at all